# Spark persist dataset when saving as parquet and writing into redshift

Tags: apache-spark

Does it make sense to try to persist the dataset when needing to write to parquets in s3 and save it into redshift?

```
dataset.write
    .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).parquet(s"s3a://s3path")

dataset.write.format("com.databricks.spark.redshift")
  .option("url", redshiftJdbcUrl)
  .option("dbtable", "table")
  .option("tempdir", s"s3a://s3PathTemp")
  .mode("append")
  .save()
```

And what about in this case where I write to parquet, save to redshift, and also need to grab max id to save in s3 separately?

```
 val lastId: String = dataset.describe("id").filter("summary = 'max'").select("id").collect()(0).getString(0)
 Seq(lastId).toDS().coalesce(1).write
  .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
  .text(S3PathMaxId)
```